# Convergence of $ \begin{equation} \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty{\frac{{{{\left( {2 +\sin n} \right)}^n}}}{{{3^n} \cdot n}}} \end{equation}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Determine whether the following series is convergent or not, with explanation.
$$
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( {2 + \sin n} \right)}^n}}}{{{3^n} \cdot n}}} 
\end{equation}
$$
I guess the above series is disvergent, but I cannot prove it. I have the following  assumptions:

1. The function $\sin n$ has least upper bound one for counting number $n$.
2. In each 'cycle', there will be a positive number $n_k$ which lets $\sin n_k \to 1$.

Then I just consider all positive numbers $n_k \left(k=1,2,\cdots\right)$
$$
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{{n_k}} {\frac{{{{\left( {2 + \sin n} \right)}^n}}}{{{3^n} \cdot n}}} \to \sum\limits_{{n_k}} {\frac{1}{n}},
\end{equation}
$$
it looks like a harmonic series.

**PS.**

I used **MATLAB** to find the maximum of $\sin n$ within a certain range.

```
n=1:1e4;[m,index]=max(sin(n));
```

Then, I got $\rm{m}=1.0000$ and $\rm{index}=9929$.

Comment: I would break up the general term with the binomial theorem and then show each sum converges. But i am not sure it works

Comment: @Milan, while this would work with a finite n, a sum of infinite convergences is not necessarily convergent.

Comment: Sin n can only become 1 if n is transcendental? But n is a counting number.

Comment: hint: try to look at it as a geometric sequence with a reason smalker than 1 multiplied by $1/n$

Comment: @Souames, I know that, however, there is an infinite number of convergence points like a geometric sequence and an infinite number of divergence points like a harmonic series.

Comment: The  numerator is always less than $3^n$, so each term is (at least a bit) smaller than $1/n$. I'd guess convergent. Try the root test (many powers)...

Comment: I’d guess convergent too, but I definitely don’t know, since I expect that $\forall \epsilon >0, sin(n) > 1-\epsilon$ infinitely often.

Comment: We must find some kind of precise measure of _just how often_ that happens.

Comment: This property could help https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3333804/503397

Comment: Also this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3337261/503397

Comment: It seems that Raab's test, Bertrands's test, Gauss's test all fail, and do not provide a conclusion.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#4._Gauss’s_test

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is ok as an answer, but I can't comment yet.
I put it in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282%2Bsin%28n%29%29%5En%2F3%5En%2Fn%20convergence), which says it doesn't converge.
Not sure how it tests that, though.

About Jones' answer, I'm not sure you can claim the strict inequality after taking the limit.