# Is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\Bigl(\frac{2+\sin n}{3}\Bigr)^n =0 $; $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigl(\frac{2+\sin n}{3}\Bigr)^n $$ where $n$ is a natural number.

The problem is if the numerator is less than 3. I think it is because $\sin  n$ is never $1$ otherwise $\pi$ would be rational. But i am not sure if the limit exists because $\sin$ oscillates. How to solve this ?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri those are not subsequences.

Comment: You need to put $n$ an integer in your question.

Comment: @Mike It is convention that $n\in\mathbb N$. Everybody knows this. So no need to do this.

Comment: I made a graph. Here is the [link](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing/zeqmqt9v)

Comment: For $n=573204$ the argument of the limit is very close to $1$, and there are infinite similar cases, granting that the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 4):

The value of the limit, if existing, depends on how close to $1$ (and how often) $\sin n$ can be. Of course $\sin n\approx 1$ iff $n$ is close to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ plus an integer multiple of $2\pi$. Let us consider the convergents $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ of the continued fraction of $\pi\not\in\mathbb{Q}$: they all fulfill
$$ \left|\pi q_n-p_n\right| \leq \frac{1}{q_n}. $$
Let us assume $\color{red}{p_n\equiv 0\pmod{2}\text{ and }q_n\equiv 1\pmod{4}}$, i.e. $p_n=2a$ and $q_n=4b+1$. Then

$$ \left|\frac{\pi}{2}(4b+1)-a\right| \leq \frac{1}{8b} $$
implies $|1-\sin a|\leq\frac{1}{a}$, so $\left(\frac{2+\sin a}{3}\right)^a$ is at least as large as $\exp\left(-\frac{1-\varepsilon}{3}\right)$.

For the same reason $\left(\frac{2+\sin p_n}{3}\right)^{p_n}$ is extremely close to zero, hence the limit *does not* exist, provided that the red constraint holds infinitely often.

Comment: OP I accidently downvoted your answer. I just upvoted. My apologies

Comment: Why is $1-\sin a\le\tfrac 1a$? When I use your line below the red part, I get $1-\sin a\le\tfrac 1{8b}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio No, $\frac a{4b+1}\approx\frac\pi 2$, hence $\frac a{4b}\approx\frac\pi 2$ and so $\frac{b}a\approx\frac 1{2\pi}$. But that also does it, thanks.

Comment: @amsmath: of course you are right. Still $\frac{8}{2\pi}\gg 1$, so the inequalities above are fine.

Comment: I edited, thanks.

Comment: How did you get $|1-\sin a|<1/a$, and also everything after

Comment: @Milan: $\sin$ is a $1$-Lipschitz function, so if $a$ and $b$ differ by less than $d$, then $\sin(a)$ and $\sin(b)$ also differ by less than $d$. The final part just follows from $\left(1+\frac{C}{n}\right)^n\approx e^C$ for any $n$ large enough.